# Parse a XML String with android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I'm trying to parse a `String` with xml saved in. I've got this class created, but I don't know how to do to pass my `String` to this class, and then take values within the tags.

My `string` contains this `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><productes><producte><id>4</id>      <nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Aigua</nom><preu>1.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>6</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel</nom><preu>11.00</preu><descripcio>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>22</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Amanida verda</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>17</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Cava Cuvée Santamaria 07</nom><preu>49.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>24</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Coca de sardina amb albergínia fumada i pernil</nom><preu>9.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>13</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Coulant de xocolata, ametlla garrapinyada amb gelat</nom><preu>6.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>8</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Croquetes de pernil ibèric</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>18</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Elisabet Raventós 05</nom><preu>45.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>9</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Entrecot de buey amb patates fregides</nom><preu>16.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>27</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Fanta llimona</nom><preu>1.50</preu><descripcio>Fanta de llimona</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge>./img/productes/proimg_Fanta llimona.png</imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2>./img/productes/proimg02_Fanta llimona.png</imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>5</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Filet de vedella amb bolets</nom><preu>12.00</preu><descripcio>Filet de vedella amb bolets xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>23</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Gaspatxo a la andalusa</nom><preu>7.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>25</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Graellada de verdures del temps amb salsa romesco</nom><preu>11.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>14</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Llet fregida amb mel, pinyons i un toc cítric</nom><preu>5.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>26</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Ous fregits amb xanguets i xistorra</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>7</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Ous trencats i bolets</nom><preu>9.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>19</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Perrier Jouët Belle Epoque 99</nom><preu>235.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>20</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Pouilly Fumé Silex 04</nom><preu>230.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>21</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Sopa de Cadaqués</nom><preu>11.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>11</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Tac de foie rostit amb configura casera de tomàquet i terra de fruits secs</nom><preu>9.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>15</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Tarta de formatge</nom><preu>5.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>12</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Tempura de verdura (salsa agridolça, salsa de mostassa i de soja</nom><preu>10.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>10</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Tonyina vermella marinada amb soja, gingebre i fideus cruixents darrós</nom><preu>13.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>16</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Torrija de taronja amb crema de xocolata i gelat de canella</nom><preu>7.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte></productes>
```

And my `parser` class is that:

```
public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<productexml> productes;
private productexml producteActual;
public StringBuilder sbTexto;

public List<productexml> getProductes(){
    return productes;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    super.characters(ch, start, length);

    if (this.producteActual != null)
        sbTexto.append(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
        throws SAXException {

    super.endElement(uri, localName, name);

    if (this.producteActual != null) {

        if (localName.equals("id")) {
            producteActual.setId(Integer.parseInt(sbTexto.toString()));
        } else if (localName.equals("nomordre")) {
            producteActual.setOrdre(sbTexto.toString());
        } else if (localName.equals("nom")) {
            producteActual.setNom(sbTexto.toString());
        } else if (localName.equals("preu")) {
            producteActual.setPreu(Double.parseDouble(sbTexto.toString()));
        } else if (localName.equals("descripcio")) {
            producteActual.setDescripcio(sbTexto.toString());
        } else if (localName.equals("iva")) {
            producteActual.setIVA(Double.parseDouble(sbTexto.toString()));
        }else if (localName.equals("imatge")) {
            producteActual.setImgPrincipal(sbTexto.toString());
        }else if (localName.equals("imatge_s1")) {
            producteActual.setImgDetall1(sbTexto.toString());
        }else if (localName.equals("imatge_s2")) {
            producteActual.setImgDetall2(sbTexto.toString());
        }else if (localName.equals("imatge_s3")) {
            producteActual.setImgDetall3(sbTexto.toString());
        }
        else if (localName.equals("producte")) {
            productes.add(producteActual);
        }
        sbTexto.setLength(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

    super.startDocument();

    productes = new ArrayList<productexml>();
    sbTexto = new StringBuilder();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                         String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);

    if (localName.equals("producte")) {
        producteActual = new productexml();
    }
  }
```

### EDIT

Thought @Yuva Raj question was correct answered but when I implemented my code on my project I've noticed that this code is for `Java` not for `Android`, that was a good try by him for someone is looking for an answer to `java` question, but this question is for `Android`.

If you need more code or more explanation about my question just let me know and I'll paste the code or reply you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple when you use `xmlPullParser`. Here's your xml file with neat layout :

```
<productes>
    <producte>
        <id>4</id>
        <nomordre>beguda</nomordre>
        <nom>Aigua</nom>
        <preu>1.00</preu>
        <descripcio></descripcio>
        <detall></detall>
        <iva>21.00</iva>
        <imatge></imatge>
        <imatge_s1></imatge_s1>
        <imatge_s2></imatge_s2>
        <imatge_s3></imatge_s3>
    </producte>
    <producte>
        <id>6</id>
        <nomordre>entrant</nomordre>
        <nom>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel</nom>
        <preu>11.00</preu>
        <descripcio>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</descripcio>
        <detall></detall>
        <iva>21.00</iva>
        <imatge></imatge>
        <imatge_s1></imatge_s1>
        <imatge_s2></imatge_s2>
        <imatge_s3></imatge_s3>
    </producte>
    ....
    ...
    ..
    </productes>
```

[Here](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html) is the nice tool even you can try it out.

Code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class TestClass {


    static String text;

       public static void main (String args[])
                 throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
             {
                 XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                 factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                 XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

// your xml content

                 String xmlString = "<productes><producte><id>4</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Aigua</nom><preu>1.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>6</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel</nom><preu>11.00</preu><descripcio>Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>22</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Amanida verda</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>17</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Cava Cuvée Santamaria 07</nom><preu>49.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>24</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Coca de sardina amb albergínia fumada i pernil</nom><preu>9.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>13</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Coulant de xocolata, ametlla garrapinyada amb gelat</nom><preu>6.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>8</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Croquetes de pernil ibèric</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>18</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Elisabet Raventós 05</nom><preu>45.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>9</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Entrecot de buey amb patates fregides</nom><preu>16.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>27</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Fanta llimona</nom><preu>1.50</preu><descripcio>Fanta de llimona</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge>./img/productes/proimg_Fanta llimona.png</imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2>./img/productes/proimg02_Fanta llimona.png</imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>5</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Filet de vedella amb bolets</nom><preu>12.00</preu><descripcio>Filet de vedella amb bolets xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>23</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Gaspatxo a la andalusa</nom><preu>7.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>25</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Graellada de verdures del temps amb salsa romesco</nom><preu>11.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>14</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Llet fregida amb mel, pinyons i un toc cítric</nom><preu>5.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>26</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Ous fregits amb xanguets i xistorra</nom><preu>8.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>7</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Ous trencats i bolets</nom><preu>9.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>19</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Perrier Jouët Belle Epoque 99</nom><preu>235.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>20</id><nomordre>beguda</nomordre><nom>Pouilly Fumé Silex 04</nom><preu>230.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>21</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Sopa de Cadaqués</nom><preu>11.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>11</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Tac de foie rostit amb configura casera de tomàquet i terra de fruits secs</nom><preu>9.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>15</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Tarta de formatge</nom><preu>5.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>12</id><nomordre>entrant</nomordre><nom>Tempura de verdura (salsa agridolça, salsa de mostassa i de soja</nom><preu>10.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>10</id><nomordre>segon</nomordre><nom>Tonyina vermella marinada amb soja, gingebre i fideus cruixents darrós</nom><preu>13.50</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte><producte><id>16</id><nomordre>postre</nomordre><nom>Torrija de taronja amb crema de xocolata i gelat de canella</nom><preu>7.00</preu><descripcio></descripcio><detall></detall><iva>21.00</iva><imatge></imatge><imatge_s1></imatge_s1><imatge_s2></imatge_s2><imatge_s3></imatge_s3></producte></productes>";

                 // passing your xml here
                 xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlString));
                 int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                 // parses till it finds the end of document
                 while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    // gets the tag name here                   
                     String tagname = xpp.getName();

                     switch (eventType) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                              if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("producte")) {
                                   System.out.println("<prdoucte>");
                                }                         

                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            text = xpp.getText();
                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("producte")) {
                                   System.out.println("</prdoucte>");
                            } 

                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                                   System.out.println("Id is : " +text);
                                } 

                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("nomordre")) {
                                   System.out.println("nomordre is : " +text);
                                } 

                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("nom")) {
                                   System.out.println("nom is : " +text);
                                } 


                            // ....add what are the tags you want


                        default:
                            break;

                    }

                  eventType = xpp.next();
                 }
             }

}
```

The code above are all self explanatory. You can check out the documentation if you want.

And, here's the output. In this case, i'm grabbing the content from some tags like id, nomordre, nom. If you want you can add more tags in the below `case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:`:

```
<prdoucte>
Id is : 4
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Aigua
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 6
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Amanida de formatge de cabra, nous i vinagreta de mel
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 22
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Amanida verda
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 17
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Cava Cuvée Santamaria 07
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 24
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Coca de sardina amb albergínia fumada i pernil
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 13
nomordre is : postre
nom is : Coulant de xocolata, ametlla garrapinyada amb gelat
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 8
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Croquetes de pernil ibèric
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 18
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Elisabet Raventós 05
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 9
nomordre is : segon
nom is : Entrecot de buey amb patates fregides
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 27
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Fanta llimona
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 5
nomordre is : segon
nom is : Filet de vedella amb bolets
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 23
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Gaspatxo a la andalusa
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 25
nomordre is : segon
nom is : Graellada de verdures del temps amb salsa romesco
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 14
nomordre is : postre
nom is : Llet fregida amb mel, pinyons i un toc cítric
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 26
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Ous fregits amb xanguets i xistorra
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 7
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Ous trencats i bolets
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 19
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Perrier Jouët Belle Epoque 99
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 20
nomordre is : beguda
nom is : Pouilly Fumé Silex 04
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 21
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Sopa de Cadaqués
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 11
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Tac de foie rostit amb configura casera de tomàquet i terra de fruits secs
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 15
nomordre is : postre
nom is : Tarta de formatge
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 12
nomordre is : entrant
nom is : Tempura de verdura (salsa agridolça, salsa de mostassa i de soja
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 10
nomordre is : segon
nom is : Tonyina vermella marinada amb soja, gingebre i fideus cruixents darrós
</prdoucte>
<prdoucte>
Id is : 16
nomordre is : postre
nom is : Torrija de taronja amb crema de xocolata i gelat de canella
</prdoucte>
```

Comment: I thought was right but when i try to implement that,  I've noticed you've cast by java and not for android

Comment: Where you face problem?